# Pinterest API calls failing - internal server errror

Tags: fetch-api, internal-server-error, pinterest

This is an internal server error so it seems to be an issue on Pinterest's side. I've tried a few things but these accounts always seem to have the internal error.

Here's an example URL that caused the problem:
URL: https://api.pinterest.com/v1/boards/533324849561780294/pins?access_token=AX1gRVqQ2O-VNVVlWy1wAkz3JDvAFDeLJQ7Eom1C53m7hgAuWgAAAAA&fields=url,creator,created_at,counts,image,color,media,attribution,note,link

> Exception Error: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
> Response:
> {"message": "A InstantContentBlockField was passed an unknown block_type: text", "type": "api"}

Answer (score 0):

Remove "link" from the fields you will get normal response.